# Asp.Net C# Page Validate Error on post: 'Page.IsValid' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, post

I am implementing PayPal in many forms and one simple form runs into this problem.

```
Page.Validate(FormEntryBase.VALIDATION_GROUP);
return Page.IsValid;
```

If I submit the form using a asp:Button click it works fine. In the debugger, hovering over IsValid shows true or false correctly based on the page field settings.

If I submit the form using an PayPal button looking anchor which calls a JavaScript function that does a form submit, then hovering over IsValid before the Page.Validate call shows the message:

```
 'Page.IsValid' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
```

After the Page.Validate called, IsValid is always false, regardless of the page values.  The RadCaptcha (Telerik control) always says the value does not match. Other validation issues are correct.

The anchor calls PayPalClick. The JavaScript submit is quite simple

```
function PayPalClick() {
    document.getElementById("<%= PurchaseDone.ClientID %>").value = "PayNow";
    MembersForm.submit();
}
```

The PurchaseDone value is always set correctly.

I have 7 other form pages doing the same thing, setting more fields, without any problems.

This page was working yesterday with the JavaScript submit, but now always fails on the validate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that calling `PageValidate()` form Page_Load causes a problem. Calling `PageValidate()` from the click handler works fine, never seeing the HttpException. It must be a asp.net page life cycle issue of some sort.

Happily, the HtmlAnchor class has ServerClick handler to easily add click handler. I did not need to change my anchor class styles to work on a button.